# Create methods in object in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, oop, object

Can anyone help me for solving this question.I can't understand how we access methods from functions

> **Task**: implement a function to create a "user" object.
>
> **Technical requirements**:
>
> Write the `createNewUser()` function, which will create and return the `newUser` object.
>
> The function should ask the caller for the name and surname during the call.
>   Create an object newUser with properties firstName and lastName, using the data entered by the user.
>
> Add the `getLogin()` method to the `newUser` object, which will return the first letter of the user name connected to the user surname, all in lower case (for example, Ivan Kravchenko → ikravchenko).
>
> Create a user using the `createNewUser()` function. Call the `getLogin()` function from the user. Display the result of the function execution in the console.
>
> An optional advanced complexity assignment:
>
> Make the properties `firstName` and `lastName` cannot be changed directly. Create setter functions `setFirstName()` and `setLastName()`, which will allow you to change these properties.

This is how I approached this, but it doesn't work:

```
let user = {
    firstName:firstName,
    lastName:lastName,
    createNewUser:function(){
        this.firstName=prompt("Enter your first name: ");
        this.lastName=prompt("Enter your last name: ");
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    },
    getLogin:function(){
        return `${this.firstName[0]}+${this.lastName}`.toLowerCase();
    },
    setFirstName:function(){
        this.firstName=prompt("Set your first name: ");
    },
    setLastName:function(){
        this.lastName=prompt("Set your last name: ");
    }
}

user.createNewUser();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es6_objects.htm

Comment: Please show us your good faith attempt at solving this.  We would be happy to *help* you get your solution working, but are less keen on doing your homework *for* you.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started check out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

```
class User {

constructor(first, last) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
}

getLogin(){
// Your code here

}

var person = new User("John", "Doe");
```